# Querying a field having nested objects in Elasticsearch

Tags: object, elasticsearch, nested

I have a type called **jobdetails**. The type contain professional experience related details of employees. Each **employee** document have an experience filed which is type nested.

```
"experience": 
    {

        "type": "nested",
        "properties": 
        {
            "company": {
                "type": "string"
                   },
            "title":{
                "type": "string"
                    }
        }
    }
```

I would like to know how to fetch employees having only “manager” or “teacher” but not “trainee” experience in their experience field.

For Ex:

```
doc 1: experience[
{“company”:“xxx”, “title”:”manager”}, 
{“company”:“xxx”, “title”:”teacher”}, 
{“company”:“xxx”, “title”:”trainee manager”},]

doc 2: experience[{“company”:“xxx”, “title”:”manager”}]

doc 3: experience[{“company”:“xxx”, “title”:”teacher”}]

doc 4: experience[
{“company”:“xxx”, “title”:”manager”},
{“company”:“xxx”, “title”:”teacher]
```

The required query should return doc2, doc3, doc4 but not doc1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query like the following one should do the trick, i.e. we're looking for documents whose `experience.title` field contains either `manager` or `teacher` but not `trainee`

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "experience",
                "filter": {
                  "terms": {
                    "experience.title": [
                      "manager",
                      "teacher"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "experience",
                "filter": {
                  "terms": {
                    "experience.title": [
                      "trainee"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```